# Facing Issue while connecting Entity framework with Oracle 11g using MVC 4

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database through Entity Framework.

I have created two projects:

1. A data access project
2. MVC4 Web project

It is working fine if I try to connect using a console application and App.config, but facing issue when trying to connect using web application and web.config.

I have added packages using Nuget in data access project. I referenced the data access dll in web project and trying to call the oracle connection.

**Package.config**

```
<packages>    
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />    
  <package id="odp.net.x64" version="112.3.20" targetFramework="net45" />    
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="12.1.021" targetFramework="net45" />    
  <package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" version="12.1.021" targetFramework="net45" />    
</packages>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>    
  <configSections>    
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->    
    <section name="entityFramework"    
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"    
             requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />    
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>    
    <clear/>   
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"    
         connectionString=" Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host address)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oracle))); User Id=userid;Password=pwd;"/>    
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>    
    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>-->    
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" >    
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

    <providers>    
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"  
          type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>    
    </providers>  

  </entityFramework>

  <system.data>

    <DbProviderFactories>    
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />    
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />    
    </DbProviderFactories>   
  </system.data>

  <runtime>    
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>    
  </runtime>

  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>    
    <version number="*">    
      <dataSources>    
        <dataSource alias="OracleDbContext" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oracle))); User Id=userid;Password=pwd;"/>    
      </dataSources>    
    </version>    
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>    
</configuration>
```

I am facing the issue below:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Comment: The web project can't find the "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" libraries, maybe they need to be added to the web project? You could try adding the Nuget packages to the web project as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following and it started working.

I just commented the  defaultConnectionFactory line in web.config

```
<entityFramework>

    <!--<defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" >

    </defaultConnectionFactory>-->

    <providers>

      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"

        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>

      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>-->

    </providers>

  </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case Ajay's answer doesn't resolve the issue for anyone:

As per @jjj's comment, I had to add a reference to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, even though I had already installed the pacakge that had this DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a proper assembly qualified name.

If you are not sure of it, you can check what the name is using AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@""). And copy it to your config.

For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb(v=vs.110).aspx

I had faced the exact same error. This solution worked fine.